# Spring Framework Primeface Theme not working

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

I want to set the bootstrap theme and have followed the steps describe here 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml

I use maven and added the repository

```
<repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

and added the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I can clearly see the `all-themes.jar` in the maven dependencies so I guess the steps above work as expected. After that, I added the following to `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunately, nothing changed since then. I still get the default theme without any error (neither in the eclipse output nor in the web console) indicating what is wrong.

Comment: You have definitely followed all the steps correctly.  So something else must be wrong.  In your XHTML are you somehow overriding the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did not find the issue. 
There was no theme specified ANYWHERE ELSE.
I downloaded the jar manually, extracted the css, importet it into the ressources folder and linked it manually in the main html

Comment: This is not a solution but a weird workaround. Sure the jar was used/put in the war?

Comment: Yes The jar was set correctly. I think the problem was, that the primefaces.THEME param was no recognized. I have found out that you can set it to none there to remove all css which also did not had any effect.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, puzzling.